# How to debug Go program taking 100% CPU randomly

Tags: performance, go, debugging

I have a Go application which randomly starts using 100% CPU after its running for 2-3 days. The CPU usage stays 100% unless the application is killed. I haven't been able to figure out which goroutine is causing the issue. I installed pprof there which works as expected when application is running normally but when CPU goes to 100% even pprof stops responding.

I was able to get the following stacktrace logs by running `kill -3 1`

https://gist.github.com/lokesh-wise/1804b3dc4fe2df2d31f97fae70e1d6f8

(There are 2 log files, one for application running in bad state (100% CPU) and other for application running in good state.)

Any idea which goroutine is the culprit or how can I find what's causing 100% CPU?

Comment: More details are needed here like what libraries you're using, what code you've written, are you keeping certain variables forever in the app when they are supposed to be disposed much earlier, are there deadlocks in your system etc. You can use pprof tool as well to get the info.

Comment: In my experience 100% CPU usually is a fast loop somewhere. Sometimes an error case leads to a fast loop that usually would not occur. In OK state all your routines are idle, waiting for IO, in a select, etc. In BAD state, almost all your routines are runnable. Maybe that is something to look into.

Comment: With 100%, do you mean all CPUs or one CPU? How many CPUs does the program have available?

Comment: @TehSphinX The program runs on one CPU machine.

Comment: @AmitKr pprof stops responding once CPU goes to 100%.

Comment: You can use a debugger and stop the program when it takes 100% of the CPU to see where it is. An alternative solution is to use a sampling-based profiler like `perf` on Linux.

Comment: @Lokesh You can use `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)` to avoid the CPU hogging while you are debugging and monitoring your application. Your bug is probably in the the accept loop for a sock or more narrowly in a Read loop.

Comment: Ok, that (only one CPU) explains why pprof won’t work any more if the program goes into BAD mode. Maybe you can debug on a machine with more cores, that way you can get profile information once the program has entered the bad state.

Comment: @Mihai Shouldn't I use a value greater than 1 since its already running on one core because of which pprof isn't responding?

Comment: As far as I know, the current default value is your number of cores which means it will use all your available cores if you do not invoke Gomaxprocs to limit it at least to one core, after which for debugging purposes you can use Gosched in the place in your loop, maybe a conditional where you think it will get stuck.

Comment: Hi all. I created a simple program with infinite loop and ran it inside a docker with only 1 CPU using the flag `--cpuset-cpus="0"`. I found out that pprof was still responding even with 1 CPU. Are you sure that moving to multiple core machine would make the pprof work?